# Track which Facebook like button was clicked

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I have more Facebook like buttons on my websites and I was wondering if there's any way to track which one of them was used.

Is there any way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "track" directly on the page, no. The "Like" button is in an `iframe` element, you will have no access to it due to the Same Origin Policy.

If you mean "track" as in track it afterwards through the API, I asked a similar question once:  [Creating "Like" buttons for arbitrary elements on my site, and reading back the status - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3520938) and got a hint about the [API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) - not sure whether this can be done there  (I never followed up on it), but maybe worth a look.

Comment: I am using the XFBML and I was wondering if I could use the FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create' function to track which one of the buttons was clicked. I went through the FB API docs, but I didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: @Alex yup, same here  - I didn't find my way through that, either.

Comment: Please let me know if you find any solution to this :)

Answer (score 6):

Have you checked the [Like Plugin FAQ in the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)?

> **What is the best way to know which
>   Like button on my page generated the
>   traffic?**
>
> Add the 'ref' parameter to the plugin
>   (see "Attributes" above).

Examples:

```
<fb:like ref="top_left"></fb:like>
<iframe src="...&ref=top_left"></iframe>
```

I suppose the info should appear in the Facebook Insights page.

Comment: Yeah, that was my backup solution :)

Comment: "Backup solution?" It seems like this is _the_ solution.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Definitely this is the solution (not a backup!), but I thought I was missing something here. Thanks for bumping up this question in my inbox, don't even remember that I have read the first comment in 14th May :-)

Comment: The SO front page seems to be bumping old questions up for me at the moment, and I don't know why! Didn't even notice that this is an "old" question.

Comment: This looks like the best solution to me, but how can you track Likes coming from a 'Page plugin'? rather than a 'Like plugin'? there is no 'ref' parameter...

Answer (score 6):

To track your Facebook Like Buttons the easiest way is to use the [XFBML like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). You'll need a Facebook Application ID to do so.

Steps to implement, you need to add a custom XML namespace to the `<html>` tag else it won't work in IE, e.g.:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Then place the following code under the `<body>` tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'YOUR_FB_APPID',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (href, widget) {
            // do stuff when something is liked
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function (href, widget) {
            // do stuff when something is unliked
        });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.src = 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
</script>
```

Then add your Facebook Like buttons on your web page like so:

```
<fb:like href="http://mydomain.com/path/to/page" send="false" layout="button_count" width="80" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

Cheers!

Comment: The confusion starts here, people tend to think that if an app id is needed, the users have to be connected via FB-Connect which is not right in this case. Thank you!